# Контекст функции

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите как передать в функцию getMouse контекст нашего объекта, что бы оно видело console.log(this.ourdiv.style);

```js
import React from "react";



class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let deltaX;
    let deltaY;
    this.state = {
      divStyle: {
        width: "1000px",
        height: "500px",
        outline: "1px solid red",
        position: "relative"
      },
      move: {
        width: "200px",
        height: "100px",
        outline: "1px solid green",
        position: "absolute"

      }
    }

  }

  getMouse(e) {
    console.log(this.ourdiv.style);

  }


  MouseDown(e) {
    var mousePosX = e.pageX;
    var mousePosY = e.pageY;
    console.log(this.ourdiv.style);
    var divPosX = this.ourdiv.offsetLeft;
    var divPosY = this.ourdiv.offsetTop;
    this.deltaX = mousePosX - divPosX;
    this.deltaY = mousePosY - divPosY;
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.getMouse);
    this.ourdiv.onmouseup = function() {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.getMouse);
    }
  }


  render() {

    return ( <
      div >
      <
      div style = {
        this.state.divStyle
      } >
      <
      div style = {
        this.state.move
      }
      ref = {
        (ourdiv) => this.ourdiv = ourdiv
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.MouseDown.bind(this)
      } > < /div> <
      /div> <
      /div>
    )

  }
}



export default Main;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужен context == window?

Comment: Мне нужно что бы работало

Comment: getMouse(e){
           console.log(this.ourdiv.style);

        }

Comment: мало кода - добавьте

Comment: Добавил больше кода

Comment: Код Reactjs jsx

Comment: Обработчик у вас на window,вот и получаете window...Сохраните this в переменную например context

Comment: Ок понял, просто думал можно сделать

Comment: А как потом эту переменную передать в getMouse?